# where-object, Print All Parameters

Tags: powershell

How can I print out the whole object here, cause where-object seems to just print out the parameter name

```
> Get-ChildItem -path Cert:\* -Recurse | where-object {$_.Name -like '*remote*'}

Name : Remote Desktop
```

If I for example issue this command, it prints out all of it:

```
> Get-ChildItem -path 'Cert:\*' -Recurse | out-string -stream|select-string -pattern "remote" -Context 1,9
> Name : Remote Desktop

  Subject      : CN=foo
  Issuer       : CN=foo
  Thumbprint   : 321C08A023F0B44C3AD0C5145E90C0432F0FBA55
  FriendlyName :
  NotBefore    : 08/05/2023 11:02:13
  NotAfter     : 07/11/2023 10:02:13
  Extensions   : {System.Security.Cryptography.Oid, System.Security.Cryptography.Oid}
```

Comment: Your original code is working as expected - `Remote Desktop` is a container, not a certificate, so doesn't have many other properties to show.  If you're wanting all details of the certificates inside `Remote Desktop`, then you can get them like this: `Get-ChildItem -path 'Cert:\LocalMachine\Remote Desktop' | Format-List *`.  If you want to get all certs in containers starting with 'Trust', for example, try: `Get-ChildItem -path Cert:\ -Recurse | Where-Object PSParentPath -like '*Trust*' | Format-List *`

Comment: You could add "Select-Object -Property *" to get all available properties.